# SetText gives error on device but not in emulator

Tags: emulation, settext

I am getting a problem transfering the text from an `EditText` to a `TextView` (I have also tested transfering it to an `EditText` with the property enable set to false) and it works OK on the emulator but when I test it on the real device, it always crashes when it attempts to set the text.

I have also tested sending just a text (see commented line) with the same result

```
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Texte);
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) 
        {
            int A;
            boolean handled = false;
            if (arg2.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
            {
                TextView Etiqueta = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
                Etiqueta.setText(arg0.getText().toString());
                //Etiqueta.setText("40");
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way using the onKeyListener that don't gives error

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    TextView Etiqueta = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
    TextView Etiqueta2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
    EditText myEditText = (EditText) view;

    if ( event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)  
    {        
       if (!event.isShiftPressed()) 
       {
            //Log.v("AndroidEnterKeyActivity","Enter Key Pressed!");
            switch (view.getId()) 
            {
            case R.id.Texte:
                 Etiqueta.setText(myEditText.getText());
                 break;
            case R.id.Texte2:
                 Etiqueta2.setText(myEditText.getText());
                 break;
            }
            return true;
       }               
    }
    return false;
}
```